# What would happen if you reduced the coupling of $SU(2)$ in the standard model to zero?

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, weak-interaction

Ultimately, my goal is to find a free parameter that you could change in order to significantly reduce the strength of, or eliminate, the weak interaction. Would such a modification leave other parts of the Standard Model unchanged?

Comment: This question (v2) seems quite broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to see, even though your ultimate vision should be in trouble. I assume you mean decrease the coupling *g* of *just* SU(2), and leave the EM coupling *e* and the Higgs v.e.v. *v* alone, which cannot be done.

You then just look at the formulas:
$$\cos \theta_\text{W} = \frac{g}{\,\sqrt{g^2+g'^2\,}\,}, \qquad     \sin\theta_\text{W} = \frac{g'}{\,\sqrt{g^2+g'^2\,}\,}  \\
 e=g\sin\theta_W= g'\cos \theta_W\\
 m_\text{Z} = \frac{m_\text{W}}{\,\cos\theta_\text{W}\,}, \qquad  m_W= {ev\over 2\sin\theta_W}, \qquad G_F= 1/(v^2\sqrt{2}). $$

[image]

As $g\to 0$, the Weinberg angle increases to π/2, its cosine vanishes, and its sine goes to 1.

- But note, the EM charge *e*  cannot stay invariant, since $e\to g$.

The Fermi constant stays put; the mass of the W  goes to zero (it stops coupling!), and the mass of the Z goes  to $g'v/2$.

---

*NB aside*: If you are seeking decoupling, the opposite limit, $g\to \infty$, paradoxically is better behaved, and often taught in class: in that case, *e* can stay unchanged, $e=g'$, since $\theta_W=0$, the cos is 1, and $m_Z=m_W=\infty$, while the Fermi constant is what it always was: the old Fermi theory! So you may think of EW unification as a descent from infinite to a finite *g*...

Comment: Thank for your answer!

Comment: Wait - I have a question. In your postscript, are you saying that you can eliminate the weak interaction by increasing $g$ to $\infty$? What does it mean to have bosons with infinite mass? Perhaps it would be also interesting to explore a more intermediate case - what if $g$ was significantly larger?

Comment: Not eliminate! Hide the gauge bosons thereof! The Fermi constant stays the same, so the four-fermion interaction is still what it was for 40 years (1933-1973), when they didn't quite know how heavy the vector bosons were! Plug *g* s twice, 10 times, 100 times the real value!

Comment: Wouldn't the weak force still exist where you have virtual particles mediating the interactions? Although a temporary disturbance in the quantum field with infinite mass is crazy to think about...

Comment: As I said, the 4-fermi interaction, and beta decay, etc... would *still* be operative at low energies; only the virtual vector bosons would he absent. You are doing yourself a disservice if you try to visualize these phenomena as disturbances in quantum fields.  I gathered you were familiar with the mainstream working of the standard model....

Comment: Ahhh, okay i see